# Domain SSL is not working for port 9002

Tags: ssl

I have example.com domain with SSL certificate. I tried to include http://example.com:9002 URL into *https://example.com* page using iframe. But i am getting the error like *Blocked loading mixed active content*

Please help to fix this in server. I tried to change headers using .htaccess file *Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15):

You are including an HTTP iframe on an HTTPS website. All assets, including your iframe need to be HTTPS.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent

Comment: Thank you, but how can we exclude some insecured scripts?

Comment: Remove them from your source code.